# String to Number conversion is not working

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic3

I have an input like below. You can see that where it converts `budget` `numeric` property into thousands Separators (e.g. `1,000`).

```
<ion-input [ngModel]="project.budget | thousandsSeparatorPipe" 
(ngModelChange)="project.budget=$event;calculateContingency()" 
    formControlName="budget" type="text"></ion-input>
```

Here it is not working:

```
calculateContingency(eve:any) {
   this.project.contingency = ((Number(this.project.budget) * this.project.contingencyPercentage) * 1 / 100);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

It shows like this:

[image]

can you tell me how to sort out this issue? Or How can I use the `budget` model without thousand separators? If I can get that then I can send it to above calculation method no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **`parseFloat`** with a regex to replace the comma,

```
 this.project.contingency = ((parseFloat(this.project.budget.replace(/,/g, '')) * this.project.contingencyPercentage) * 1 / 100);
```

**DEMO**

```js
var budget = '1,000';
var buget2 = 1000;
var contigency =  parseFloat(budget.replace(/,/g, '')) + buget2;
console.log(contigency);
```

Comment: You did it again. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply remove the "," from the string before trying to convert it to Number.
just use `STRING.replace(',','')`. Should work like a charm.

For example:

```
    calculateContingency(eve:any) {
   this.project.contingency = ((Number(this.project.budget.replace(',','')) * this.project.contingencyPercentage) * 1 / 100);
    this.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
  }
```

Comment: This works up to this `10,000` after that not working. e.g. 10,0000

Comment: Works for 10,00000 as well, it just removes the comma from the string and returns it.